# How to use a properties file that contains numbers properties in shell

Tags: linux, shell, properties-file

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I am pretty sure it would have been answered already (it is a pretty dumb question, I think, as I just started to learn Linux scripting), but I did'nt succeed to find an answer yet.

Sorry for that.

Here is my problem: I try to use in a shell a number given in a property file, I have an error because the number is not taken "as it is".

I have a **prop.properties** file :

```
sleepTimeBeforeLoop=10
```

and a  **test.sh** shell :

```
#!/bin/sh
. prop.properties

echo "time="$sleepTimeBeforeLoop
sleep $sleepTimeBeforeLoop
```

When I launch test.sh I have the following **Output**:

```
time=10
sleep: invalid time interval `10\r'
Try `sleep --help' for more information.
```

What I understand is that my properties files was correctly sourced, but that the property was taken as a string, with some special character to indicate the end of the line, or whatever.

How can I do to take only the "10" value?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is line endings issue / make sure your script files are terminated by `\n` (the unix way)
eg. write it in UNIX text editor or use a windows one capable of saving in "unix style"

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am working on a Linux server (with a Red Hat distribution, as it seems), and I have always use Vi to create, edit and save my two files (the properties and the shell files). Shouldn't it be ok?
I've never had problems with Vi before.

Comment: The `\r` after the number is the line ending / your editor is using `\r\n` and bash expects `\n` only.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your answer, I would never have expected something like that. Whit your help, I remembered I didn't actually "create" the properties file, but copy another one I found to modify it the way I want. The original file must have been created on DOS...
For those who have the same problem, I only use dos2unix command on my properties file, and everything works fine.
Thanks again!